# mysql comparing two date fields against two date strings

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```
select
start_date,stop_date_original
from dates
where 
start_date is not null
and stop_date_original is not null 
and start_date > str_to_date('10/10/2009','%d/%m/%Y')
/*and stop_date_original < str_to_date('01/24/2013','%d/%m/%Y')*/
```

this query works fine but when i uncomment the last line or use it to replace the one before the result doesnt get affected or i get an empty result set.

are there issues with this approach that might cause this behaviour?

also, are the null checks intrinsically necesarry across different database systems?

Comment: Please show some example data and expected result.

Comment: You just change your filter condition and can get different result in order empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop date has to be `24/01/2013`, not `01/24/2013`:

```
select
  start_date,
  stop_date_original
from
  dates
where 
  start_date is not null
  and stop_date_original is not null 
  and start_date > str_to_date('10/10/2009','%d/%m/%Y')
  and stop_date_original < str_to_date('24/01/2013','%d/%m/%Y')
```

or you have to invert day and month on your function `str_to_date('01/24/2013','%m/%d/%Y')`.

Also, if `start_date` is null, or if `stop_date_original` is null, the condition would be evaluated as null anyway so you don't need to check if they are not null, although this make things more readable.